# Generating unique sequential surrogate Key for each record in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing difficulty in generating unique sequential surrogate Keys to replace the null values in a column of a table. The table is obtained after joining a source table and reference table and the column is the primary key column ("account_key") of resultant table where null values should be replaced with unique sequence keys.
The unique keys generated should start with a number assigned to the source and the number should be incremented for each null value.
I tried the following

```
    var uniqueId = Table_NO.agg(max("No"))
// var uniqueID = 6000001 (for example)
//or a SQL statement can be written as "var uniqueId = sqlContext.sql(SELECT MAX (NBR) FROM Table"
    var a = sc.accumulator(uniqueID)
    def generate(s:Int):Int = {
        if (s==0)
        {
            a = a.add(1)
            return a.localValue
        }
        else
        {
            return s
        }
val NumGen = udf(generate(_:Int))
val KeyGen = table_n.withColumn("KEY_New", NumGen(table_n ("account_key")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use a windowing function, depending on your version it might look like this...

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val incrementbyOne = Window.partitionBy(lit("C")).orderBy(lit("C").asc)
    table_n.withColumn("identity_column", row_number().over(incrementbyOne))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6.3 version

Comment: I found this formula in an ETL tool but unable to implement the same in Spark.  (next_in_sequence() * number_of_partitions() + this_partition()+1 -number_of_partitions())+${maximum sequence number} your suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I will also try the windowing function you suggested. Thanks